# Magento 1.9.2.3 Product SHORT description is not displaying in the product page

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I am using a custom template on 1.9.2.3 , and I have provided a short description while adding the product in Admin Panel.

I am expecting to see the SHORT description somewhere below the product Name or Above Product Price.
[image]

**However**, the short description is not displaying.

**My question:** Am I missing any configuration in the Admin panel?

Or Am I required to make some changes in the some files in order to display the short description? If yes, which file has to be modified.

Comment: call description in `view.phtml`

Comment: @GopalPatel, Where is view.phtml located at? is it in code or design folder? I am new to Magento and it's folder structure. Thanks.

Comment: `design/frontend/YOUR_THEME/default/catalog/product`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code to call short description in design/frontend/your_package/default/catalog/product/view.phtml

```
<?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
      <div class="short-description">
          <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
   </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: This solution works like a charm! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are showing on home page then go to `app/design/frontend/yourtheme/yourpackage/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` and add this code snippet

```
<div class="desc std">

<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="link-learn"><?php echo $this->__('Learn More') ?></a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Magento 1.9.2.3 Product SHORT description is not displaying in the product page

Use the below-mentioned to include product short description on the product page:

```
<?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
            <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?>
        <?php endif;?>
```